# Custom keyboard shortcut to enter specific unicode on windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Coming with a muscle memory for entering half-space with Shift+Space on Linux, now I find the same shortcut useless on Windows. On the other hand, I don't see a way to define the shortcut for entering the character on Windows. There is recommendation over the net to use Ctrl + Shift + 3 for entering it on Windows. It works on Windows 10, but again, I see no way to customize it and ideally change it to Shift + Space (same as Linux).
**So, any ideas on how I can define a custom keyboard shortcut on Windows to enter semi-space (or any unicode character available in Character Map) anywhere I write text (and not just a specific app like Office)?**

Already did a bit digging in Windows and couldn't find a thing.

More info on semi-space: according to [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/half-space-semi-space-between-words/75bfe733-fe45-47c8-a935-88ffb8848098), the character is called "four·per·em space or ¼·em space, represented by Unicode character U+2005".

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on how I can define a custom keyboard shortcut on Windows to enter semi-space (or any unicode character available in Character Map) anywhere I write text (and not just a specific app like Office)?

You may want to have a look at [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). You should be able to set up a shortcut such as:

```
+Space:: Send {U+2005}
```

In this case, `+` is the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
and `Space` is the <kbd>Space</kbd> key (an overview of available hotkeys can be found [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)). `Send` simply sends a given keystroke or set of keys.

*Caveats*

- AutoHotkey and the script above (an `.ahk` file, which is a simple text file) need to be running in order for the shortcut to work.
- Many shortcuts combinations should be just fine, but you can (theoretically) run into conflicts with the OS or built-in program shortcuts.
- Being able to type a Unicode character into a program does not mean the program recieving the text will automatically represent it correctly (or be able to represent it at all). That is, you may just get e.g. a blank box.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by changing the keyboard type from **Persian** to **Persian (Standard)**. Now, pressing Shift + Space key combination enters the half-space character mentioned in the question. This is the keyboard type used by Linux (Fedora at least).